# Update table with summary by column key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
declare @rooms table
(
depa_key int,
room_key int,
d1 int,
d2 int
)

insert into @rooms(depa_key, room_key, d1, d2)
select 1, null, null, null
union all
select 1, 1, 1, 1
union all
select 1, 1, 1, 1
union all
select 2, null, null, null
union all
select 2, 1, 5, 3
union all
select 2, 1, 7, 2
union all
select 3, null, null, null
union all
select 3, 1, 6, 9
union all
select 3, 1, 5, 8
```

Table is populated with:

[image]

What I would like to do (but I don't know how) is populate summary rows (rows where `romm_key is null` with summary from that `depa_key`.

Row where room_key is null is summary row. Only departments does not have room_key (because department means all rooms). Each room has room_key and depa_key.

Example:

First row (depa_key = 1, room_key = NULL) should be populated with:

```
D1   D2
2    2
```

Second row (depa_key = 2, room_key = NULL) should be populated with:

```
D1   D2
12   5
```

There will be a lot of depa_keys in the future (table is changing dynamic), so query must also be dynamic.
I could type depa_keys one by one (update queries), but I can't do this. How to update columns d1 and d2 with summaries from that depa_key dynamically?

Comment: Do you only have row per depa_key where room_key, d1 and d2 are null? I am guessing that the values are the sum of the values for that depa_key? How will you know that one is the "summary" row and the others are not?

Comment: Row where room_key is null is summary row. Only departments does not have room_key. Each room has room_key.

Comment: Right but once you update this how will you know which row is which?

Comment: room_key is null in summary rows. select * from @rooms where room_key is null gives me departments.

Comment: I would suggest a more explicit way of handling your data. You are putting a lot of assumption into null which is risky. Your columns allows null so your data model has no way of ensuring there is only null per depa_key. And you seem to be mixing two types of rows in a single table. This is a sign of some pretty sketchy design.

Comment: @SeanLange - any suggestions how to improve design?

Comment: In this situation I would use two tables. One for department and another table for rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.

```
declare @rooms table
(
depa_key int,
room_key int,
d1 int,
d2 int
)

insert into @rooms(depa_key, room_key, d1, d2)
select 1, null, null, null
union all
select 1, 1, 1, 1
union all
select 1, 1, 1, 1
union all
select 2, null, null, null
union all
select 2, 1, 5, 3
union all
select 2, 1, 7, 2
union all
select 3, null, null, null
union all
select 3, 1, 6, 9
union all
select 3, 1, 5, 8


UPDATE @rooms
SET d1 = a.d1, d2 = a.d2
FROM (
        SELECT depa_key, SUM(D1)d1, SUM(d2) d2
        FROM @rooms
        GROUP BY depa_key
    ) a
    JOIN @rooms r ON
        a.depa_key = r.depa_key
WHERE r.room_key IS NULL


SELECT *
FROM @rooms
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution with CTE looks more readable.
At first we take aggregated information for `depa_key` taking only records for rooms where `room_key IS NOT NULL`. Then we update rows where `room_key IS NULL`by this aggregated data.

```
;WITH DepaStats AS
(
    SELECT
        depa_key     AS depa_key,
        SUM(d1)      AS sum_d1,
        SUM(d2)      AS sum_d2
    FROM @rooms
    WHERE room_key IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY depa_key
)
UPDATE R
SET
    d1 = S.sum_d1,
    d2 = S.sum_d2
FROM @rooms R
LEFT JOIN DepaStats S
    ON S.depa_key = R.depa_key
WHERE R.room_key IS NULL
```